# Find a point given another point and angle

Tags: circles

I have something starting at (50, 10) it then rotates counter clockwise by 30 degrees, around the point at (50, 0), essentially mapping out an arc of a circle. How do I find the point it now lies on?

Answer (score 0):

You apply a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to the vector from the center of rotation to the point that is rotating.  Here the vector is $(50-50,10-0)=(0,10)$.  Then you multiply that by $\begin {bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end {bmatrix}$, getting $$\begin {bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} 0\\10 \end {bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix} 10\sin 30^\circ \\10\cos 30^\circ \end {bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix} 5 \\5 \sqrt 3 \end {bmatrix}$$ and add that to the center, getting $(50+5,0+5\sqrt 3)=(55,5\sqrt 3)$

Comment: sorry I meant 50, 0

Comment: What is the angle in 10 cos 0, and where did the 30 in the 10 sin 30 come from?

Comment: The $\theta$ should have been $30^\circ$, which you specified in your question.  The $10$ comes from the radius-the distance from the center of rotation to the point of interest.